# Scrape CSS to bulk-check responsiveness

Tags: html, css, xpath, responsive-design, web-scraping

I have a list of web domains and would like to check if they are built to be mobile-responsive. A fairly sure way to check this manually is to see if there are "@media" queries in the style.css.

I've used XPATH (IMPORTXML) previously to bulk-check for strings on webpages, but I don't see an obvious way of importing the css files in bulk and search for a string within them. Is there a way to do this? Ideally, I'd like to accomplish it in Google Sheets or with Google Apps Script.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Google's Mobile-Friendly Test](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/) if you want to use a GUI.

If you want to use a REST API, try this (replace url parameter for what you want to test):

`https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v3beta1/mobileReady?url=http://facebook.com`

This will return a JSON object. It will return lots of useful info, but if you are just looking for mobile friendliness, look for the `true` or `false` result here:

```
"ruleGroups": {
  "USABILITY": {
   "pass": true
  }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I was aware that Pagespeed does this, but wasn't aware that you can tease the responsiveness apart from the JSON output.

As a follow-up, I see that there is a 'screenshot' output in the JSON - is this something I can actually use to save a screenshot image somewhere?

Comment: A screenshot is included at the end of the JSON result: `"screenshot": {
  "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
  "data": "........"}`.

Comment: Thanks - actually I saw this but wasn't sure how to convert to an image. I initially thought it was in base64, but can't seem to decode it as such...

Comment: I had the same issue too - apparently the base64 encoded string is invalid. See this [comment in a google thread about this issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-api-python-client/DjbJ0BwjbPo/lCEUt-dmnRwJ) to fix it. It worked for me!